# Docker on Raspberry Pi 2: Could not reach any registry endpoint

Tags: docker, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I installed docker on my Raspberry Pi 2 and want to pull some images. But when I try to pull with `docker pull nginx`, I get `Could not reach any registry endpoint`. My network connection is ok and even `docker search nginx` echos all images. I installed docker from the raspbian repository with `sudo apt-get install docker.io` so it is an older version. I wasn't able to install a newer version. The docker version is 1.3.3.

Also asked in:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51029/docker-on-raspberry-pi-2-could-not-reach-any-registry-endpoint

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @jarvis11 said, Docker stopped supporting client versions below 1.5.
At the same time, the current version available for raspbian jessie is 1.3, so you will have to install from source or one of the binaries.

Basically, step 4 here:

https://github.com/umiddelb/armhf/wiki/Get-Docker-up-and-running-on-the-RaspberryPi-(ARMv6)-in-four-steps-(Wheezy)

Answer (score 1):

Docker stopped supporting client versions below 1.5, so make sure you have client v1.5 and above.

Docker engine is not able to connect with the registry. 
I have faced these issues a year back, its due to the load on docker hub. (https://status.docker.com/) 
Public registry should work just fine now.

Comment: Where have you seen that docker stopped supporting client versions below 1.5?